# Problema con header y foreach (headers already sent by)

Tags: php

Tengo una problema con un formulario en el cual tengo varios checkbox. Esto es para que puedan escoger varios servicios.

Los checkbox tienen como value a los campos
`id_del_servicio,id_de_descuento` juntos. Esto es para que después en el PHP, con un foreach, los vaya separando e insertando en sus respectivos campos.

El problema es cuando esté en línea: el header me manda un error a los foreach que están vacíos. Es decir, a los servicios que no se seleccionaron y obviamente no me direcciona.

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started
```

```php
<?php
foreach(($_POST['horno']) &horno  as $horno){
    //$horno1=$horno[0];
    //$horno2=$horno[1];        
};

foreach($_POST['refrigerador'] as $ref){
    //$ref1=$ref[0];
    //$ref2=$ref[1];        
};

foreach($_POST['ventanas'] as $ven){
    //$ven1=$ven[0];
    //$ven2=$ven[1];        
};

foreach($_POST['lavado'] as $lav){
    //$lav1=$lav[0];
    //$lav2=$lav[1];        
};

foreach($_POST['planchar'] as $pla){
    //$pla1=$pla[0];
    //$pla2=$pla[1];        
};

foreach($_POST['hogars'] as $hog){
    //$hog1=$hog[0];
    //$hog2=$hog[1];        
};

$user=$_POST['Usuario'];
$cliente = (int)$user; 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "call sp_segundopaso_servicio('.$cliente.','.$horno[0].','.$horno[1].','.$ref[0].','.$ref[1].','.$ven[0].','.$ven[1].','.$lav[0].','.$lav[1].','.$pla[0].','.$pla[1].','.$hog[0].','.$hog[1].')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

   header('Location: ../domicilio.php');

} else {

}
$conn->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Antes del header()   no puede haber ninguna salida, (ni siquiera un warning )
justo la parte del mensaje más importante no lo pusiste ***(output started...*** , ahí te dice en que parte del script estás generando una salida previa al header

algunas veces para evitar esos mensajes te basta con un @ en la línea, por ejemplo

```
<?php
$fp = @ fopen( '/etc/shadow', 'r' );
if ( $fp === FALSE )
{
  header( 'Location: /acaVanLosMalos.html' );
}
```

Comment: Una pregunta Juan Manuel que es la ruta entre parentesis en fopen?

Comment: es un ejemplo de algo que sin el @ te daría un error antes del header, en este caso trata de abrir un archivo "secreto" de linux.  Pero la intención es mostrar como evitar que el código genere avisos de advertencia de ua forma sencilla

Comment: Haber espera, yo creo que debes empezar a debuguear, te recomiendo que al inicio de este código coloques lo siguiente: `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>";` con esto tu podrás saber realmente que datos estas recibiendo, coloca su resultado y después ya vemos como resolver la situación.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba pasándole al header una ruta absoluta, sí esto no funciona siempre puedes usar esta alternativa:

```
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=tu_pagina.php">';
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda, un saludo.